# Image classification- Why am I getting vastly different results training on Tensorflow vs Pytorch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch

I am training an image classifier for a robot that detects "blocked" vs "free" paths. Using the same data on pytorch gives >0.98 accuracy on validation data whereas tensorflow only gives around 0.50-0.60 accuracy with a mode of 52.17%.

Pytorch is using pre-trained [AlexNet implementation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torchvision/models/alexnet.html#alexnet) for which there is no counterpart on tensorflow. I tried my best to mirror the implementation on tensorflow as you can see below. I have also tried other CNN models including ResNet and InceptionV3 but all give me roughly the same validation accuracy on tensorflow.

Other information:

- Input images are (224, 224, 3)
- Both implementations point to same training and validation directories
- I've tested both models with 4 images they have not seen before and pytorch model guessed correctly whereas tensorflow model did not.

Pytorch Code:

```
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    train_dataset,
    batch_size=8,
    shuffle=True,
    num_workers=0
)

test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    test_dataset,
    batch_size=8,
    shuffle=True,
    num_workers=0
)

model = models.alexnet(pretrained=True)
model.classifier[6] = torch.nn.Linear(model.classifier[6].in_features, 2)

device = torch.device('cuda')
model = model.to(device)

NUM_EPOCHS = 30
BEST_MODEL_PATH = 'best_model.pth'
best_accuracy = 0.0

optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

for epoch in range(NUM_EPOCHS):

    for images, labels in iter(train_loader):
        images = images.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(images)
        loss = F.cross_entropy(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    test_error_count = 0.0
    for images, labels in iter(test_loader):
        images = images.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)
        outputs = model(images)
        test_error_count += float(torch.sum(torch.abs(labels - outputs.argmax(1))))

    test_accuracy = 1.0 - float(test_error_count) / float(len(test_dataset))
    print('%d: %f' % (epoch, test_accuracy))
    if test_accuracy > best_accuracy:
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), BEST_MODEL_PATH)
        best_accuracy = test_accuracy
```

Tensorflow code:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(11, 11), strides=(4, 4), activation='relu',
                        input_shape=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3)),
    keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2)),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=192, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding="same"),
    keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2)),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding="same"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(1, 1), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding="same"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(1, 1), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding="same"),
    keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2)),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    keras.layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])


train_gen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1.0 / 255,
    samplewise_std_normalization=True,
    # rotation_range=20,
    # width_shift_range=0.2,
    # height_shift_range=0.1,
    brightness_range=(0.0, 0.5),
    # shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.3,
    fill_mode='nearest'
)

val_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0 / 255)

train_data = train_gen.flow_from_directory(
    train_path,
    target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
    class_mode='binary',
    color_mode='rgb',
    batch_size=8,
    shuffle=True)

val_data = val_gen.flow_from_directory(
    val_path,
    target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
    class_mode='binary',
    color_mode='rgb',
    batch_size=8,
    shuffle=True)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
loss = tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=['accuracy'])
num_epochs = 40
save_path = 'F:\\Documents\\Jetbot\\collision_avoidance_tf\\model_save'
model_checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(save_path, monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True)
history = model.fit(train_data, epochs=num_epochs, validation_data=val_data, verbose=1,
                    callbacks=[model_checkpoint])
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You are training the Tensorflow version from scratch and the PyTorch version has the pretrained weights?

Comment: Correct. I am curious however if that is the main reason? As I mentioned, I tried with ResNet152 and Inception V3 using their pretrained weights and got the same results. Pardon me, I am somewhat new to deep learning. I can try to find pretrained weights for Alex Net and put those in TensorFlow. Conversely, maybe I can rule that out by setting use pre-trained weights to false in pytorch.

Comment: Yes that is the main reason. In PyTorch the model is technically already trained for you and you just use the weights that the model has learnt on the new data. It's called transfer learning and saves a lot of time as we don't have to train models from scratch everytime. In Tensorflow you're starting from 0 by training the model. Also note that in the original paper it was trained for 90 epochs instead of 40 like you did. Try changing it to that and you should have similar results.

Comment: *"In PyTorch the model is technically already trained"*, well not unless you say so: `torchvision`'s models are not loaded pretrained by default.

Comment: @Ivan I meant in this code `pretrained` is set to `True` after all.

Comment: After setting `pretrained = False` in PyTorch, the accuracy dropped to 0.5217. It was my error in implementing transfer learning in Tensorflow that caused the drop of accuracy. Trying again with InceptionV3 using `'imagenet'` I got a validation accuracy of 0.9130 in Tensorflow. Thank you both!